# ifelse to combine and convert messy month/year data over two columns in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm working with a dataframe that has very messy age data for children. Some is in months, some in years. I need a new column with only age in months. Looks like this

```
G4_R_2_mth   G4_R_2_yr
        18           1
        NA          16
        NA           6
        NA           4
         0          16
         0          17
         0          16
         5           7
         0           8
         0          10
         0          16
        11           0
```

Basically I want an `ifelse` that creates a new column, saying if "G4_R_2_mth" is a number, keep this number, but if "G4_R_2_mth" is `NA` or 0, give the value G4_R_2_yr*12.

I tried the following:

```
child$agemonth <- ifelse(child$G4_R_2_mth == '0 | NA', child$G4_R_2_yr*12, child$G4_R_2_mth)
```

But got this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "agemonth", value = logical(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 1102
```

Maybe my error is simple but I appreciate the help. One of a ton of problems and driving me crazy.

Comment: I'm guessing one source of your problem is that your column names don't match. In your data, it says 'Month', but in your code it says 'G4_R_2_mth'. Is that intentional?

Comment: `'0 | NA'` is a string. You don't have such string in "Months" column. You need something like `with(child, ifelse(G4_R_2_mth == 0 | is.na(G4_R_2_mth), G4_R_2_yr*12, G4_R_2_mth))`.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the help. These solutions mostly still throw the same error, even after messing with my data a bit more. Probably something up with the dataset I just don't understand yet. Using @neerajt's came up with the following, which works great:                                                                   ` `>month<-as.numeric(child$G4_R_1_2_mth)
     >year<-as.numeric(child$G4_R_1_2_yr)*12
   > child$agemonth <-  ifelse((!is.na(month) & (month > 0)),month, year)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
child$agemonth <- ifelse((!is.na(child$G4_R_2_mth) & (child$G4_R_2_mth > 0)),
    child$G4_R_2_mth,
    child$G4_R_2_yr * 12)
```

Edit: Good call, cleaned it up and took out the [i]'s!

Answer (score 0):

`'0 | NA'` is a string. You don't have such string in "G4_R_2_mth" column. You need something like:

```
child$agemonth <- with(child, ifelse(G4_R_2_mth == 0 | is.na(G4_R_2_mth), 
                       G4_R_2_yr*12, G4_R_2_mth))

child
#    G4_R_2_mth G4_R_2_yr agemonth
# 1          18         1       18
# 2          NA        16      192
# 3          NA         6       72
# 4          NA         4       48
# 5           0        16      192
# 6           0        17      204
# 7           0        16      192
# 8           5         7        5
# 9           0         8       96
# 10          0        10      120
# 11          0        16      192
# 12         11         0       11
```